# Displaying a picturre from image picker?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I would like to display an image which I get from image picker. The problem is that the image is not displayed. Here is my code:

```
<img ng-src="{{images[0].src}}" width="100%" />

var options = {
        maximumImagesCount: 1,
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        quality: 80
    };

    $scope.imagePressed = function () {
        $cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options)
            .then(function (imagePath) {

                console.log(imagePath);

                $scope.images[0].src = imagePath;

            }, function(error) {
                // error getting photos
            });
    }
```

The output from `console.log(imagePath)` is:

> file:///data/data/com.ionicframework.oo943640/cache/tmp_Screenshot_2015-12-12-13-23-141582014060.png

But the image is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

you review following code:

html file

```
 <button class="button button-block button-balanced" ng-click="imagePressed()">

 <p ng-repeat="img in images">
    <img ng-src="{{img}}" />
 </p>
```

controller.js file

```
 $scope.images = [];

        var options = {
                maximumImagesCount: 1,
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
                quality: 80
            };

            $scope.imagePressed = function () {
                $cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options)
                    .then(function (results) {

                     for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                     $scope.images.push(results);
                     console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
                    }
                  }, function(error) {
                        // error getting photos
                  });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to bind to a primitive item in an array. This will not work due to how Angular handles this situation. What you can do is bind to an object in the array instead. Try something like:

```
<img ng-src="{{images[0].path}}" width="100%" />
```

and

```
$scope.images[0].src = {path: imagePath};
```

Comment: It is an object. I have mistaken the html part. I update the code. That's the way I add placeholders firstly and then change the src to the picked image:
$scope.loadImages = function() {
            
            for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                $scope.images.push({id: i, src: "https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/194077/Placeholder.png"});
            }
        }

Comment: Ok, try <img ng-src="images[0].src" width="100%" /> (without the curly brackets).

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Firstly, the image should be converted to base64. As a guide I used http://www.clearlyinnovative.com/ionic-framework-camera-image-uploads-and-base64-strings. This is my snippet of code:

```
$scope.imagePressed = function (number) {

            $cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options)
                .then(function (imagePath) {

Camera.toBase64Image(imagePath.toString()).then(function (base64string) {

                    $scope.images[number].src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64string.imageData.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, "");
                });

            }, function(error) {
                // error getting photos
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            });
        };
```

Where the Camera class is from the guide to which I pointed out above.
Secondly I updated the meta tag to allow images from base64:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

That's it. I hope it will help someone else with the same problem.